# Get one unique System ID with Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I make application with flex builder. Now I want to generate only one unique system ID. 
I tried this code

```
import mx.utils.UIDUtil;

var myUUID:string = UIDUtil.createUID();
```

problem is this code generate several IDs in several times. I want to generate one unique ID. If I close program and open it, it wants to display same Id...

How I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this unique id to be unique for the all application executions on any system/machine? If that's the case, then @micapam's answer seems very relevant.

OTOH, if what you want is to generate a unique id on each system your app runs on (sort of do a first run type execution), then you can store your unique id in a [local shared object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal%28%29). At each run, you can read the value from local shared object if it exists. Else generate a unique id, store it and use it.

Do note, that local shared objects are like browser cookies. A user would have control over allowing storage of local shared objects. Similarly, the user can go ahead and clear the local shared objects.

Comment: The second para of the answer is applicable to your case then.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you simply generate a single system ID outside your application, and then hard-code it (or put it into a config file).

There are many ways to generate a UUID, some of which are as easy as visiting a web page, e.g.:http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen